# OBIEE 11g Agents - Email Distribution List - Not working

Tags: oracle11g, obiee

I'm trying to send a report to an email distribution list. I tried to create an OBIEE agent following the oracle documentation. The agent is delivering the report only if an individual email id is added to the recipient list. If I add email distribution list (which has about 30 members) to the recipient list then its not delivering report to any of the members of this email DL. I'm not getting any errors either.

The individual email id I tried is an OBIEE user however the email DL is not.

Do you know if this is a known bug in OBIEE 11g or is there any additional config needed to achieve this?

Thanks,
NBL.

Comment: The question with the distribution list is rather: How is that managed in the email server (like Exchange)? Does the email server comprehend if it is passed this DL from an external source? It's more an email issue than a BI one.

Comment: Thanks Chris for your response. I'm nearly convinced that it is more down to the permissions on the email DL and not to do with OBIEE. However I have one more investigation to complete to be absolutely sure on this. I will update this post after I complete that investigation.